# How to get entities cached in a GET action, in the POST action without database roundtrip?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As an example how would i make it so that in the following code the POST action can get the entities cached in the GET action.

Intellisense tells me that `DbSet.Find()` will check the context to see if the entity is cached before hitting the database. In this case the `DbSet.Find()` in the POST action *does* hit the database which means that nothing is cached. So what has changed between the GET action and the POST action that the entities have disappeared?

Do I really have to pull an entity back from the database again just to delete it?

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private testContext db = new testContext();

    // GET: /User/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(user);
    }


    // POST: /User/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        db.Users.Remove(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not cached in the db, thereby hitting the db and retrieving a cached result?

Comment: maybe, but my point is why is it not available in the context as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete without a round trip to the database, you can do something like:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    User user = new User {UserID = id};
    db.Users.Attach(user);
    db.Users.Remove(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I'm not really trying to do the caching myself. I'm just trying to use EF in the way in which it is supposed to work (according to the documentation). The DbSet.Local property gives you access to cached entities, this has a count of 1 in the GET action but in POST action it is 0.

Comment: @comenica I edited my answer to show how to delete without a round trip to the database. The reason things aren't cached is the context is being destroyed at the end of each HTTP request. If you were to request the same object, with the same data context in the same request, Entity Framework does have it cached at that point and would prevent the trip to the database.

Comment: Yeah i guess that must be it. I thought that because the context is at class level all actions would use the same one. Kind of confusing. I'll give this a go tomorrow.

Comment: In a stateful application like a desktop application, you're correct. The context would stay around until you did something with it (i.e. quit the application, disposed of the class, etc). But because the controller is a class that is built on every web request, the context stays around for just that single HTTP web request.